# How to decode this string? with simplified chinese character

Tags: python, utf-8

I am going to decode this string: "\xE7\x92\x90\xE7\x94\xB8\xE5\x99\xBE\xE7\x81\x9E\xE7\x82\xB0\xE5\x94\xAC\xE9\x90\x9E", but fail.

The python code I use. (with refer to [this article](http://www.voidcn.com/blog/baidu_19473529/article/p-6393955.html))

```
s = '\xE7\x92\x90\xE7\x94\xB8\xE5\x99\xBE\xE7\x81\x9E\xE7\x82\xB0\xE5\x94\xAC\xE9\x90\x9E'
ss = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
sss = ss.decode()
print(sss)
```

And here the output result:

```
D:\py>py test.py
璐甸噾灞炰唬鐞
```

However, The result chinese character string is meaningless. So I think it should be a simplified chinese string, How can I get the string in simplified version?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by copying the output word "璐甸噾灞炰唬鐞" into a .txt file, Then drag that .txt file onto chrome browser.